# Is similarity to "natural language" a convincing selling point for a programming language?

Tags: programming-languages, nlp

Look, for example at AppleScript (and there are plenty of others, some admittedly quite good) which advertise their use of the natural language metaphor. Code is apparently more readable because it can be/is intended to be constructed in English-like sentences, says they. I'm sure there are people who would like nothing better than to program using only English sentences. However, I have doubts about the viability of a language that takes that paradigm too far (excepting niche cases).

So, after a certain reasonable point, is natural-languaginess a benefit or a misfeature? What if the concept is carried to an extreme -- will code necessarily be more readable? Or might it be unnecessarily long, difficult to work with, and just as capable of producing hilarity on the scale of obfuscated Perl, obfuscated C, and eye-twisting Bash script logorrhea?

I am aware of some specialty cases like "Inform" that are almost pure English, but these have a niche that they're not likely to venture out from. I hear and read about how great it would be for code to read more like English sentences, but are there discussions of the possible disadvantages? If everyday language is so clear, simple, clean, lovely, concise, understandable, why did we invent mathematical notation in the first place?

Is it really easier to describe complex instructions *accurately and precisely* to a machine in natural language, or isn't something closer to mathematical markup a much better choice? Where should that line be drawn? And finally, are you attracted to languages that are touted as resembling English sentences? Should this whole question have just been a one liner:

```
naturalLanguage > computerishLanguage ? booAndHiss : cheerLoudly;
```

Comment: Don't you mean `MAX(naturalLanguage,computerLangauge)`?

Comment: is there anything called obfuscated Perl ? I thought everything in perl is obfuscated :-)..

Comment: @Naveen, You're right, it probably should be called Even-More-Obfuscated-Perl

Comment: Python version: `booAndHiss if naturalLanguage > computerishLanguage else cheerLoudly`. Hm.

Comment: @ToniLeigh this question is a poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see [On discussions and why they don't make good questions](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6742/31260) Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: so where would be a good place for an excellent question such as this that is somewhat fuzzy? (I was under the impression programmers could take more philosophical questions, but I stand corrected)

Comment: @ToniLeigh Nowhere at Stack Exchange I'm afraid.
["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My answer to this would be that the ideal programming language lies somewhere between a natural language and a very formal language.

On the one extreme, there's the formal, minimal, mathematical languages. Take for example [Brainfuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck):

```
,>++++++[<-------->-],[<+>-]<.    // according to Wikipedia, this means addition
```

Or, what's somewhat preferable to the above mess, any type of [lambda calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus).

```
λfxy.x
λfxy.y
```

This is one possible way of expressing the Boolean truth values in lambda calculus. Doesn't look very neat, especially when you build logical operators (such as `AND` being e.g. `λpq.pqp`) around them.

I claim that most people could *not* write production code in such a minimalistic, hard-to-grasp language.

---

The problem on the other end of the spectrum, namely natural languages as they are spoken by humans, is that languages with too much complexity and flexibility allows the programmer to express vague and indefinite things that can mean nothing to today's computers. Let's take this sample program:

```
MAYBE IT WILL RAIN CATS AND DOGS LATER ON. WOULD YOU LIKE THIS, DEAR COMPUTER?
IF SO, PRINT "HELLO" ON THE SCREEN.
IF YOU HATE RAIN MORE THAN GEORGE DOES, PRINT SOME VAGUE GARBAGE INSTEAD.
(IN THE LATTER CASE, IT IS UP TO YOU WHERE YOU OUTPUT THAT GARBAGE.)
```

Now this is an obvious case of vagueness. But sometimes you would get things wrong with more reasonable natural language programs, such as:

```
READ AN INTEGER NUMBER FROM THE TERMINAL.
READ ANOTHER INTEGER NUMBER FROM THE TERMINAL.
IF IT IS LARGER THAN ZERO, PRINT AN ERROR.
```

Which number is `IT` referring to? And what kind of error should be printed (you forgot to specify it.) — You would have to be *really* careful to be extremely explicit about what you mean.

It's already too easy to mis-understand other humans. How do you expect a computer to do better?

Thus, a computer language's syntax and grammar has to be strict enough so that it doesn't allow ambiguity. A statement must evaluate in a deterministic way. (There are maybe corner cases; I'm talking about the general case here.)

---

I personally prefer languages with a very limited set of keywords. You can quickly learn such a language, and you don't have to choose between 10,000 ways of achieving one goal simply because there's 10,000 keywords for doing the same thing (as in: `GO`/`WALK`/`RUN`/`TROD`/`SLEEPWALK`/etc. `TO THE FRIDGE AND GET ME A BEER!`). It means if you need to think about 10,000 different ways of doing something, it won't be due to the language, but due to the fact that there are 9,999 stupid ways to do it, and 1 elegant solution that just shines more than all the others.

Note that I wrote all natural language examples in upper-case. That's because I sort of had good old GW-BASIC and COBOL in mind while I wrote this. There've been some examples of programming languages that lean on natural language, and I think history has shown that they are, in general, somewhat less widespread than e.g. terse C-style languages.

Comment: If I were writing that second language, I'd have "IT" be a built-in keyword that refers to the last variable/object acted upon by the code. (Which may be the same as the last usage of "IT".)

Comment: @JAB: In a natural language-like programming language, you most likely wouldn't even have the _concept_ of keywords as we know if from "normal" programming languages.

Answer (score 14):

Well, of course, natural languages are rarely *clear, simple, clean, lovely, concise, understandable* which is one of the reasons that most programming is done in languages far from natural.

Answer (score 4):

I recently read that according to Gartner there are over **400 billion lines of COBOL source code** in active use worldwide today.

That doesn't prove anything other than that banks and governments are fond of their legacy code, but you *could* construe it as a testament to the success of English-like programming languages. I'm not aware of any other programming language that is so close to English and so verbose.

---

Aside from that, I tend to agree with the other respondents: Programmers prefer not to type so much, and in general a language based on mathematics-like shorthand is both more expressive and more precise than one based on English.

There's a point where terse, expressive code looks like line noise. Perl, APL and J come to mind as examples with "illegible one-liners." Programmers are humans, and it may be beneficial to leave them with *some* similarity to natural language to give their brains something familiar to hold on to. Thus, I propagate a happy medium that's reminiscent of but not too close to natural language.

Answer (score 4):

"When a programming language is created that allows programmers to program in simple English, it will be discovered that programmers cannot speak English." ~ Unknown

Answer (score 3):

In my (not so) humble opinion, no.

Natural language is full of ambiguities. Normally we do not think of them because humans can easily disambiguate them, based on many criteria often unavailable to the computer. First off we have knowledge about the world (elephants don't fit in pajamas), but also we use more senses than just hearing when we speak to each other, body language to name one. The intonation and manner things are said with also helps alot to disambiguate. It is harder to catch irony or sarcasm in written text, which is more or less a transcription of what we would say, more in the case IM less in the case of well written articles. In general there is loads and loads of ambiguity in natural language, for instance where the PPs, prepositional phrases attach:

```
 "Workers [dumped [sacks [with flour]]]"
 "Workers [dumped [sacks] [with a fork-lift]]]"
```

Any human immediatly tells where the PP will attach, its reasonable to have sacks with flour in them, and its reasonable to use a fork-lift to dump something. Another very troublesome area is the word "and" which messes up the grammar horrendously, or all the references we use, the pronouns in general, but also more complex references, ie. "Bill bought a Dodge Viper, sadly the car was a lemon".

So we have three options, keep the ambiguities in and try to deal with them, accepting very many errors in disambiguation and very very slow parsing, no LALR or LL will work here, or try to make an artifical grammar resembling natural language, and keeping it deterministic, which is more reasonable but still horrible. We now have a language that falsely resembles English, but it isn't which is confusing. We have none of the benefits of a proper syntax and none of the benefits of natural language, but an oversized overwordly monstrum, with a diffcult and unintuitive grammar, diffcult to learn and slow to write.

The third way is realizing we need a succinct way of expressing ourselves, which can also be processed by a computer, not resembling any natural language, but focusing on being an unambigous description of an algorithm. This will increase the readability, especially if we compare to a very precise natural language counter part. This is why many people prefer to also read the pseudo-code when dealing with difficult problems or advanced algorithms, it relieves us of the trouble with dealing with ambiguities, and is more optimal for expressing computer instructions.

Answer (score 2):

The issue isn't so much that it's easier to describe complex ideas using one approach or the other, but it certainly is easier *understanding* machine languages (at least for machines). The biggest issue is, as always, **ambiguity**. Computers are terrible at understand it, so most grammars for programming languages *need* to be constructed to either remove all ambiguity, or the general language must be constructed so that ambiguity isn't actually a problem (this is tricky).

Any programming language that allows for ambiguity would be *terribly* error prone; and any natural language that *doesn't* allow ambiguity would be terribly verbose and convoluted (I'm looking at you, Lojban [ok, maybe Lojban isn't so bad‚ still…]).

The propensity some people show for preferring natural languages for programming languages might essentially root out in the desire to eventually be able to input a physics textbook into a parser, whereupon it'll do your homework when asked.

Of course, that's not to say that programming languages shouldn't have *hints* of natural language: Especially for OOP it makes good sense to have calling grammar resemble natural grammar, like in Obj-C, which is sort of a game of mad libs:

```
[pot makeCoffee:strong withSugar:NO];
```

Doing the same in BrainFuck would be, well, a brainfuck, three full pages of code to flip a switch will do that to you.

In essensce; the best languages are (probably) the ones that *resemble* natural languages, without pretending to be one. (Avoiding the uncanny valley of programming languages, [if there is such a thing] if you will. [Subclauses! Yay!])

Comment: Gerald Jay Sussman wrote a physics textbook called *Structure and Interpretation of Classical Mechanics* which uses Scheme instead of traditional mathematical notation, precisely *because* of the problem of ambiguity. The fact that this also allows you "to input a physics textbook into a parser, whereupon it'll do your homework when asked" is just a side-effect of that, the main goal is to make physics easier to learn by not having to struggle with arcane, ambiguous, informal notation.

Answer (score 1):

A natural language is too ambiguous to be used as programming language. It has to be artificially constrained to eliminate ambiguities.

But it defeats the purpose of having a "natural" programming language, because you have its *verbosity* and none of its advantages in expressibility.

Answer (score 1):

I think the fourth language I coded professionally in (after Fortran, Pascal and  Cobol) was [Natural](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATURAL). Which is a pretty obscure 4GL of 1980's vintage for developing mainframe systems against an [ADABAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADABAS) database.

Called Natural I believe because it had pretensions to be so. Supposedly management-readable like cobol, but minus the fluff.

Which should tell you that attempts at 'Natural' programming languages have a commercial history of over 30 years now (more if you count cobol) but they have pretty much lost out to languages that don't pretend to be 'natural' but do allow the programmer to define the problem succinctly. When I first started coding the 1GL -> 2GL -> 3GL evolution wasn't that old and the progression to 4GL (defined then as a more english-like programming languages) for mainstream work seem an obvious next step. It hasn't worked out that way.  If anything getting up to speed with coding now has got harder because there's more abstract concepts to learn.

Answer (score 1):

SQL was designed with natural language in mind originally. Fortunately it hasn't held on too tightly to this and advances since its conception are less "naturalistic".

But anybody that has tried to write a complicated query in SQL will tell you that its not that easy. You have worry about the range of some keywords over your query. You have this incredibly hard to understand query, that does some crazy shit, but you re-write it every time you need to change something because its easier.

Natural language programming is a bad idea. the further you get from assembly, the more mistakes you can make, not in terms of logical errors or anything like that, but in terms of having the wrong assumption about how the script interpreter/bytecode intepreter/compiler makes your code run on the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Is seems to be a great feature for beginners, or people who program as a "secondary activity". But I doubt you could reach the complexity and polyvalence of actual programming languages with natural language.

Answer (score 0):

If there was a programming language that actually adhered to all of the conventions of the natural language it mimics, then that would be fantastic.

In reality, however, a lot of so-called "natural" programming languages have far stricter syntax than English, which means that although they are easily readable, it is debatable whether they are actually all that easy to write.

What makes sense in English is often a syntax error in AppleScript.

Answer (score 0):

Everyday language *isn't* so clear, simple, clean, lovely, concise and understandable - to a computer. However, to a human, readability counts for a lot, and the closer you get to a natural language, the easier it is to read. That's why we're not all using assembly language.

If you have a completely natural language, there are a lot of things that need to be handled - the sentence needs to be parsed, each word must be understood - and there is *plenty* of room for ambiguity. That's generally not a good thing for a programming language, because then we're venturing into psychic programming - the computer has to figure out what you were thinking, which is not at all easy to get.

However, if you can make something sufficiently close to natural language - and yes, Inform 7 is probably the best example - so sentences look natural, but still have some structure you need to follow - then the code is almost instantly readable, even to people that don't know the language. There's usually also less specialized syntax to remember - because you're really just talking (a slightly modified form of) English - but if you have to do something out of the ordinary, then you might have to jump through some hoops to do that.

In practice, most languages don't bother with this, because that makes it easier for them to allow you to be precise. However, some will still hover closer to the "natural language". This can be a good thing: if you have to translate some pseudocode algorithm to a language, you don't need to manipulate it as much to make it work, reducing the risk that you make an error in the translation.

As an example, let's compare C and Pascal. This Pascal code:

```
for i := 1 to 10 do begin
  j := j + 1;
end;
```

is equivalent to this C code:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  j = j + 1;
}
```

If you had no prior knowledge of either syntax, the Pascal version is generally going to be simpler to read, if only because it's not as complex as a C for.

Let's also consider operators. Pascal and C both share +, - and *. They also both have /, but with different semantics: In C, / does an integer division if both operands are integers; in Pascal, it always does a "real" division and uses `div` for integer division. That means that you have to take the types into account when figuring out what actually happens in that line of code.

C also has a bunch of other operators: &&, ||, &, |, ^, <<, >> - in Pascal, those operators are instead named `and`, `or`, `and`, `or`, `xor`, `shl`, `shr`. Instead of relying on some semi-arbitrary sequence of characters, it's spelled out more. It's instantly obvious that `xor` is - well, XOR - unlike the C version, where there's no obvious correlation between ^ and XOR.

Of course, this is to some degree a matter of opinion: I much prefer a Pascal-like syntax to a C-like syntax, because I think it's more readable, but that doesn't mean everyone else does: A more natural language is usually going to be more verbose, and some people simply dislike that extra level of verbosity.

Basically, it's a matter of choosing *what makes the most sense* for the problem domain: if the problem domain is very limited (like with Inform), then a natural language makes perfect sense. If it's a very generic domain (like with C), then you either need far more advanced processing than we are currently capable of, or a lot of verbosity to fill in the details - and in that case, you have to choose a balance depending on what sort of users will be using the languages (for regular people, you need more naturalness, for people who know programming, they're usually comfortable enough with less natural languages and will prefer something closer to that end).

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is, who reads and who writes the application code in question?  I think, regardless of the language or architecture, a trained software developer should be writing the code, and analyze the code as bugs arise.